# How to keep rspec tests DRY with lots of "have_link"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, railstutorial.org

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm doing http://ruby.railstutorial.org right now.

From what I understand the language is supposed to follow this DRY standard wery strictly but it's so WET when it comes to test driven development in this tutorial.

For example

```
it { should have_link('Users', href: users_path) }
it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
```

Here we have lots of rows that almost looks the same.

I'we tried this

```
it "should have following links from this array" do
    [
        ['Users', href: users_path],
        ['Profile', href: user_path(user)],
        ['Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)],
        ['Sign out', href: signout_path]
    ].each { |a| page.should have_link(a[0], a[1]) }
end
```

This code works but it's looks ugly and it's more rows.

So I want to know if it's an better way to add an array to have_link method.

---

I now have a great idea but I don't know how to make it work.

This is my helper (it does not look like it did when i created this question. It is edited after an answer from Michaël Witrant)

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_these_links do |*links|
    match do |actual|
        links.each do |link|
            have_link(link.first, link.extract_options!).matches?(actual)
        end
    end
end
```

and this should now be my test

```
it { should have_these_links(['Users', href: users_path],
                        ['Profile', href: user_path(user)],
                        ['Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)],
                        ['Sign out', href: signout_path]) }
```

So this works but it's not user friendly. When I run the test and I have an link does not exist on the page it tells me that I do not have these links. But I will be able to make the helper tell me which link I'm missing.
This is my error code

```
   expected #<Capybara::Session> to have these links ["Users", {:href=>"/users"}], ["Test Link", {:href=>"/Does_not_exist"}], and ["Profile", {:href=>"/users/991"}]
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:42:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define custom matchers you can read [this feature](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher) and some [inspiration](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/124).

And write something like that:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_links do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.all? do |name, options|
      have_link(name, options).matches?(actual)
    end
  end
end
```

But IMO, your first try is the best way to write it: clean and easy to read.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've edited my question after your answer. This works whit some small edits but im still not where i will be (se my edited question).

Comment: Off-Topic: If you're able, cut you point me in right direktion of where i can find more information about "do |name, options|", I don't understand where i'm able to use multiply variables on foreach functions. (I don't realy know what to google on so just an hint will do)

Comment: You should customize the failure message. See "Custom matchers" in [the doc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers).

Comment: I'm not sure where you can find this information. It's about how ruby handles block parameters when it is called with an array. Or when `yield` is called. Maybe these keywords will help you. When you call a block with an array as the only argument, and the block accepts multiple parameters, the array is expanded. And that's what happen to your block when you call `each` on an array of arrays.

Answer (score 7):

You can write a custom matcher, but I think thats not the idea of tests and DRY.

In the code, the DRY mantra encourages to keep every piece of knowledge of your software in a unique and unambiguous place.
That is not the goal of the specs. The goal of the specs is to poof the correctness of a software in a explicit and easy to read way.

Repeat

```
it { should have_link('Users', href: users_path) }
```

if far more readable and easy to read than declaring and array of [text, url] and iterate over them, even inside some kind of custom matcher.

In test you should prefer readability over conciseness.

Comment: Even if it's not the right way of doing things i think it's an great way of learning things. I'm new to rails and ruby and to play with classes and extend them is for me an way to understand them more.

But i **will** keep your optinion in mind.

Comment: In that case the answer that Michaël Witrant gave you seems the best way. Write custom matchers is one of the best features of Rspec.